# What is Alternative of initlog (present in RHEL5) but deprecated in RHEL6?

Tags: linux, shell, rhel, cron

I am using initlog tool in a cron file to write the output of `ntpq -p` command in syslog..
But initlog command has been deprecated in RHEL6.

Now, I want know the alternative of initlog command in RHEL6.

Comment: Maybe `logger`?

Comment: Can i write a command in logger?

Comment: You can pipe a command into `logger` and `logger` will treat each line of output as its own syslog message for however long the pipe remains open.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution [from the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295782/what-is-alternative-of-initlog-present-in-rhel5-but-deprecated-in-rhel6#comment519059_295782) is to use [logger](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger), possibly as such:

```
ntpq -p | logger
```